# Binding to Window's DataContext from StaticResource

Tags: wpf, xaml

One more DataBinding question here.

I'd like to define some objects as resources for a Window in XAML. Like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <x:Array x:Key="Groups" Type="{x:Type vd:ViewFieldGroup}">
    <vd:ViewFieldGroup Caption="General" DataObject="{???}">
  </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>
```

The key concept for me here is the binding of `ViewFieldGroup`'s `DataObject` property. `ViewFieldGroup` is a `DependencyObject` and `DataObject` is a `DependencyProperty`.

What I'd like to do acheive is : binding `DataObject` to `Window.DataContext` in order for the ViewFieldGroup to access the window's ViewModel.

Now I have tried this: (I have given my Window the name "Self")

```
DataObject="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Self}"
```

Yet I don't think it works, as my PropertyChangedCallback for the `DataObject` is never fired.

Here's the declaration of `ViewFieldGroup`:

```
public class ViewFieldGroup : DependencyObject
{

public static readonly DependencyProperty DataObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "DataObject", typeof(object), typeof(ViewFieldGroup),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(DataObject_PropertyChanged)));

private static void DataObject_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: You should see a binding error message in the Output window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah but it only says the he cannot find the property "DataObject" on the object "null". Which tells me that binding does not work. If I forward the window's `DataContext` manually in CodeBehind using the `DataContextChanged` event, it works. So i think it's more the dependcy property than the binding.